# React/Redux Testing - Could not find "store" in either the context or props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-form, immutable.js

I'm new to react/redux and just getting into testing my first app with chai. I'm using redux-form/immutable and react-router, and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue when testing:

```
  1) Login
       renders a login form:
     Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(LoginForm))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "st
ore" as a prop to "Connect(Form(LoginForm))".
```

I found this issue: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/57 which seems like the same problem but the solution of adding a function that returns the children to the Router element doesn't fix the problem.

***index.jsx***

```
import {configRoutes} from './config'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>{configRoutes()}</Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

***config.js***

```
import App from './App';
import {PackageStoreContainer} from './components/Package/PackageContainer';
import {LoginStoreContainer} from './components/Login/LoginContainer';

export function configRoutes() {
  const routes = <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/packages" component={PackageStoreContainer} />
    <Route path="/" component={LoginStoreContainer} />
  </Route>;
  return routes;
}
```

***LoginContainer.jsx***

```
export class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    sessionStorage.removeItem('credentials');
  }
  submit = values => {
    this.props.dispatch(loginUser(values));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <LoginForm onSubmit={this.submit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    creds: {}
  };
}

export const LoginStoreContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

***LoginForm.jsx***

```
const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required');
const renderField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, warning}}) => (
  <div>
    <ControlLabel htmlFor="email">{label}</ControlLabel>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} className="form-control" />
      {touched &&
        ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
          (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const LoginForm = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit } = props
    return (
      <Col xs={12} md={12}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
            <Field
              name="username"
              type="email"
              component={renderField}
              label="Username"
              validate={[required]}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Field
              name="password"
              type="password"
              component={renderField}
              label="Password"
              validate={[required]} />
          </FormGroup>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </Col>
    );

};

export default reduxForm({
  // a unique name for the form
  form: 'login'
})(LoginForm)
```

***Login_spec.js***

```
describe('Login', () => {
  it('renders a login form', () => {
    const component = renderIntoDocument(
      <LoginContainer />
    );
    const fields = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'input');
    const submit = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'button');

    // expect(fields.length).to.equal(3);
    // expect(submit.length).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

***Fix***

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const createMockStore = (getState) => {
    const middlewares = [];
    return configureStore(middlewares)(getState);
};

const store = createMockStore();

const component = renderIntoDocument(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <LoginContainer />
   </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LoginContainer is a connected component `connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginContainer)`. That means it depends on the Redux store to generate the subtree, and when testing you don't have the wrapping `<Provider store={store} />` around it.

The solution is to use `redux-mock-store`:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
const mockStore = configureStore();

const component = renderer.create(
   <Provider store={mockStore()}>
      <LoginContainer />
   </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you connect a component, the `connect` function tries to find Provider with store in the parent hierarchy. If it does not find it it throws that error.

- Easy solution is to wrap each testing component with Provider.

  ```
    import reducers from "reducerPath"
    import {Provider} from "react-redux"
    import {createStore} from "redux"

    <Provider store={createStore(reducers,{})} >
        <LoginComponent/>
    </Provider>
  ```

this will solve the issue but it is expensive because you have to set this up for each component

- Easy way is to change the way how you render your app. Instead of this in `index.jsx`:

  ```
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>{configRoutes()}</Router>
    </Provider>,
     document.getElementById('app')
  );
  ```

First create a wrapper component:

```
    import reducers from "reducerPath"
    import {Provider} from "react-redux"
    import {createStore} from "redux"


   export default (props)=>{
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers,{})}>
          {props.children}       
      </Provider>
    }
```

then `index.jsx`

```
  import Wrapper from "./wrapper.jsx"

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Wrapper>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>{configRoutes()}</Router>
    </Wrapper>,
     document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

Now in testing, you can use this `Wrapper` component to wrap the testing component instead of depending anoter third party library:

```
const component = renderIntoDocument(
   <Wrapper store={store}>
      <LoginContainer />
   </Wrapper>
);
```